# Jaxb parse object to json

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb

I have following REST request:

```
@GET
@Path("/test2")
public Response test2() {
    List<StringEntity> out = new ArrayList<StringEntity>();
    out.add(new StringEntity("blah"));
    out.add(new StringEntity("blah"));
    out.add(new StringEntity("blah"));
    return Response.ok(new ObjectListResponse(out)).build();
}
```

My client gets this response:

```
{[{value:"blah"},{value:"blah"},{value:"blah"}]}
```

I need:

```
{["blah","blah","blah"]}
```

However, I can't use String.

I need to parse my class **StringEntity** as **String**

```
public class StringEntity {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let the framework do the work for you. Or do you have to use the `StringEntity` class?

```
@GET
@Path("/test2")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> test2() {
    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
    out.add("blah");
    out.add("blah");
    out.add("blah");
    return out;
}
```

For conversion please take a look at [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6851)

The `MessageBodyWriter` should be your friend.

Comment: I can't use String. StringEntity implement special interface and a can't refuse it.

Comment: I showed simple example code. This code not for realy project